# VSCode Can't Find Lua/IUP Headers

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, lua, shared-libraries, header-files

I've downloaded Lua, precompiled libraries for IUP, IM, and CD, minGW-64, and set the environmental values to the minGW folder and MyLibs (where I put the libraries) but VSCode won't recognize the headers in the .c file (keeps giving red squiggle lines). How do I fix it?

c_cpp_properties.json has  "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe" pointing to the compiler and I put "C:\Program Files\MyLibs\**" in includePath.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure that the paths in c_cpp_properties.json pointed directly to the "include" folder of each library... why I couldn't just use "C:/Program Files/MyLibs/**" when the asterisks supposedly tell VSCode to search subfolders, I don't know.

```
  "includePath": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                    "C:/Program Files/MyLibs/Lua54/include",
                    "C:/Program Files/MyLibs/iup/include",
                    "C:/Program Files/MyLibs/im/include",
                    "C:/Program Files/MyLibs/cd/include"
                ],
```